# What are the difference between gems and packages in Ruby and Rails?

Tags: rubygems, bundle

It seems that some tools, such as `rails` we can use

```
gem install rails
```

or

```
bundle install
```

to install it (if `rails` is in `Gemfile`). While some may only be `gem` tools (Rubygems?) or `Gemfile` packages?  How do they differ?

Answer (score 0):

A gem is a third-party library packaged to facilitate the addition of functions to a Rails app. Each gem has its own dependencies, installing more that a gem can cause dependencies conflicting especially considering the app is maintained through time.

You can read more there:  https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/libraries/

**gem install x** will install that gem and its dependencies to your app.  It will not care about another gem dependency.  This might cause conflict breaking your app.

Bundler is an installation manager that facilitates the management of the gem dependencies cross app. This gives a developper better confidence that the environment remains consistent at all time.

Details are available:  https://bundler.io